# node js browserify implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I want to use my custom modules on the browser. for example I have a AppConfig.js modules

```
'use strict'

var fs, configurationFile;

configurationFile =  './configs/appConfig.json';

fs = require('fs');

var AppConfig = function(){
function getMongoDbConnectionString()
{
    var configuration = JSON.parse(
        fs.readFileSync(configurationFile)
        );
    var connectionString= configuration.mongodbConnectionString;
    return connectionString;
}

    function getDistanceCondition()
{
    var configuration = JSON.parse(
        fs.readFileSync(configurationFile)
        );
    var distance= configuration.distanceBetweenTwoArmatures;
    return distance;
}

return {

    getMongoDbConnectionString : getMongoDbConnectionString,
    getDistanceCondition:getDistanceCondition


};

}

module.exports = AppConfig;
```

I want to use this modules on the browser. for this purpose I installed browserify module .

> npm install -g browserify

then go to app directory and run this command

> browserify -r ./modules/AppConfig.js:AppConfig >
>   ./public/javascripts/bundle.js

then i add this line on my html file .

```
<script src="/javascripts/bundle.js"></script>
```

now ı want to use this modules on my javascritp function .

```
var Configuration = require('AppConfig');
var configuration = new Configuration();
var connectionString= configuration.getDistanceCondition();
```

I call getDistanceCondition() function but ı take an error:

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function(…)**

how can ı fix this problem ? 
can u give me some information.

Comment: What do you think you'll be able to do in the browser with that mongodb connection string ? BTW you probably don't want all users to see it...

Comment: I will remove  mongodb connection string from this module this is not important. Firstly I want to run this code successfully . . .

Answer (score 0):

`fs` can't be browserified. However, since your configuration file is JSON, and you're only using `fs` to read that file, you can replace it by using `require()`:

```
var configuration = require(configurationFile);
```

With the added advantage that Browserify will add your configuration file to the bundle.

Comment: This won't be the end. Between serving the config file and connecting mongodb, this looks like the start of an XY problem.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I missed the MongoDB part. Unless it's the OP's intention to use MongoDB's (limited) REST interface this will indeed become problematic...